# Gulp собрать в минимизировать в один файл

Tags: javascript, gulp

Есть директория `src/less-build-structure/` с кучей файлов и папок.
Как все эти файлы, включая те, которые в папках собрать в один файл `est.min.css`
Который находится в другой директории `/build/est.min.css`
Вот мой код для минимизации:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('minify', function () {
  return gulp.src('.src/less-build-structure/**/*.*')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('.build/est.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для сборки less файлов используешь плагины предназначенные для JS файлов
2. Скорее всего не верный порядок сжатия и объединения файлов, сначала надо объединить и потом сжать, а ты делаешь наоборот
3. В `concat` нужно указывать только название файла, без пути
4. В вопросе ты не написал, что не получилось

Этот таск должен работать:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  minify = require('gulp-clean-css'),
  csshint = require('gulp-csslint'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('minify', function () {
  return gulp.src('.src/less-build-structure/**/*.*')
    .pipe(csshint())
    .pipe(csslint.formatter())
    .pipe(concat('est.min.css'))
    .pipe(minify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

Ссылки:
[gulp-csslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-csslint)
[gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat)
[gulp-clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css)

Comment: а разве будет `css task` работать для `less` ?